# Unable to Connect to Virtual Serial Port

Tags: c#, bluetooth, serial-port, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm writing a .NET application running on Windows CE 6 that creates a Bluetooth Serial Port. The call to RegisterDevice() returns successfully, and SerialPort.GetPortNames() indicates the the COM port exists. However, when I attempt to open the COM port using .NET's SerialPort class, it throws an IOException, stating that the port does not exist. If I attempt to open it using CreateFile, the call fails, and GetLastError returns error 6 (INVALID_HANDLE). However, if I create a registry key under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Bluetooth\Serial and restart the device to allow the Microsoft Bluetooth Stack to initialize the port, I can connect to the serial port without issue. I'd like to avoid making the user restart the device, if possible.

My code to create the virtual serial port:

```
static public IntPtr RegisterVirtualComPort(int index, long address, Guid service)
{
   PORTEMUPortParams portParams = new PORTEMUPortParams();
   portParams.uiportflags = RFCOMM_PORT_FLAGS.REMOTE_DCB;
   portParams.flocal = false;
   portParams.device = address;
   portParams.uuidService = service;
   IntPtr handle = RegisterDevice("COM", index, "btd.dll", ref portParams);
   return handle;
}
```

I attempt to test the COM port via P/Invoke here:

```
static public bool TestComPort(int index)
{
   string portName = string.Format("COM{0}:", index.ToString());
   IntPtr handle = CreateFile(portName, DESIRED_ACCESS.GENERIC_READ | DESIRED_ACCESS.GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE.FILE_SHARE_NONE, IntPtr.Zero, CREATION_DISPOSITION.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
   bool success = handle.ToInt32() != -1;
   CloseHandle(handle);
   if (!success)
   {
      int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      App.Logger.DebugFormat("TestComPort failed for \'{0}\', return error code {1}.", portName, errorCode);
   }
   return success;
}
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Windows CE is a pain in the ass, any hardware change needs a reboot, so I think you're out of luck without creating the registry entry and restarting the device.

Comment: You may consider using Bluetooth socket instead. No need for a virtual com port. Possibly the OEM has a SDK for the device?